# Angular Dart Import Error With Tracing.dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

I am using Angular Dart for a project.  In my pubspec.yaml I have

```
dependencies:
  browser: any
  angular: "^1.1.2+2"
  shadow_dom: any
  json_object: any   
  bootjack: any
  crypto: any
  xml: "^2.3.2"
transformers:
- angular
```

for my dependencies.  When I run my program in Dartium I get the error

```
The requested built-in library is not available on Dartium.'package:angular/tracing.dart': error: line 9 pos 1: library handler failed
import "dart:developer";
^: package:angular/tracing.dart
```

I never reference or use anything out of the tracing.dart so I'm not sure why this is causing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [tracing](https://github.com/angular/tracing.dart) package is directly using `dart:profiler`, which was deprecated and now removed. You can now use `dart:developer` instead, both libraries are compatible.

I would suggest to fork the package, replace `dart:profiler` with `dart:developer` (no other changes are required) and send a pull request. I already forked and fixed the package some time ago [here](https://github.com/Fox32/tracing.dart), but I think the original package is inactive so I didn't created an PR. You can use my fork by adding this to your pubspec.yaml:

```
dependency_overrides:
  tracing:
    git: https://github.com/Fox32/tracing.dart.git
```

Answer (score 1):

`dart:profiler` was recently renamed to `dart:developer`. One of your dependencies probably use an analyzer version that doesn't fit to your Dart version.

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1345